# How many repeated roots can the given equation have

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that $n$ degree equation has $n$ solutions in complex numbers (not necessarily distinct).

Why exactly $n.$

We say that $ x^2-2x+1=0$ has $2$ repeated roots $1,1$.

Similarly we can say that it has $1$ as a root of multiplicity $3,4,....$

Then how a $n$ degree equation can have exactly $n$ roots

I had a logic please consider and please report error

A root comes from one linear factor  so it has exactly $n$ roots .and multiplicity is that how many factors provides it.so $1$ is $2$ multiplicity root not $3,4...$

Comment: The roots of $x^2-2x+1=0$ are 1 and 1. As for your question, consider how many linear factors an $n$ degree polynomial has.

Comment: "Similarly we can say that it has 2 as a root of multiplicity 3,4,....": no, the multiplicity is $2$, nothing else. Why do you think opposite ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use either the fundamental theorem of algebra or the Vandermonde determinant, but I feel the easiest is the **factor theorem**.

**Proposition:** A polynomial of degree at most *n* with more than *n* roots vanishes identically.

*Proof:* By induction. The base case is $n=0$, which is obvious. Now take a polynomial *f* of degree at most *n*, and let $x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}$ be distinct roots of *f*. By the factor theorem, we can write $$f(x) = (x-x_{n+1})g(x)$$ where *g* plainly has degree at most $n-1$. Now substitute $x = x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. For all these values of *x* the left hand side vanishes and the factor $(x_i-x_{n+1})$ is nonzero. Hence all these $x_i$ must be roots of *g* and by induction *g* is identically zero. **QED**

This same proof works over any field (or even integral domain).

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem can be proven from a weaker version: every non-constant polynomial has a root.

Then let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and $z$ a root.

We can certainly factor $P(x)=(x-z)Q(x)$, where $Q$ is a degree $n-1$ polynomial. Hence by induction, $P$ has $n$ roots, distinct or not.